# Minifying html with Docpad

Tags: html, minify, docpad, static-pages

Is there a way to render out minified html with Docpad? For reasons I'm too lazy to explain, grunt plugins are not a viable solution for me.

Comment: You mean like Gzip your HTML files? I believe that's something your server can do on the fly before serving the content to the user. I imagine you mean that DocPad does it as part of the process though right?

Comment: No, not gzipping, just minifying, as in removing needless white-space, line ends and tabs, basically removing any unnecessary characters from the page.

Comment: Well. If you're using the CoffeeKup plugin it is possible to make it output not-nice output. So it's all in one line. Except the output from Markdown etc. Stuff that other plugins handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is possible. The CoffeeKup plugin will actually minify your HTML when generating on a production environment for you automatically, and I think the LessCSS plugin does this too.

Personally, I use CloudFlare to minify everything post-deployment: https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22076718-How-do-I-minify-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-to-optimize-my-site-

However, you could also easily write  a plugin to minify the content as well. You could base it off the [Uglify plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-uglify) which minifies javascript files using uglify-js. The trick would be to just decide which node module you would like to do it with. Happy to help further on this path with additional questions and answers.